# how to disable button when clicked in react js for quiz

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I want to disable the `button` which i have `clicked` when i choose an `option` in my quiz and the rest of the quiz options are enabled ...any ideas on how to do it for these `options` ? i know we have to use `disabled={pass a function}` but don't know how to cooperate that with the `options`

This is my **quiz.js**:

```
render() {
    const { userAns, options, scores, currentQuest } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <ProgressBar animated now={this.state.currentQuest * 10} />
        </div>{" "}
        {this.state.questions}
        <br></br> {this.state.scores}
        <br></br>
        <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Q{this.state.currentQuest}</p>
        {this.state.pictures}
        <br></br>
        {options.map((option, id) => (
          <Button
            size="lg"
            block
            key={id}
            className={`ui floating message options
      ${userAns === option ? "selected" : null}
     `}
            onClick={() => this.checkAns(option)}
          >
            {option}
          </Button>
        ))}
        <div className="hrLine"></div>
        <br></br>
        <Button onClick={() => this.checkAns()}>CHECK</Button>
        {currentQuest < Quizdata.length - 1 && (
          <Button
            disabled={this.state.disabled}
            onClick={() => {
              this.nextQuestion();
            }}
          >
            NEXT
          </Button>
        )}
        <br></br>
        {currentQuest === Quizdata.length - 1 && (
          <Button
            onClick={() => {
              this.finishQuiz();

            }}
          >
            Finish
          </Button>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: really hard to answer this without seeing it in action

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass a function to the `disabled` attribute, this is a 'boolean` value, Now you have to keep track of the options that you've been clicked.

I'm assuming that you have an array of options so first of all you need to convert that to an object of objects so you can access any option with a unique key:

```
const options = {
 0:{
    isSelected: false,
    value: 'your value 0',
 },
 1:{
    isSelected: false,
    value: 'your value 1',
 },
 2:{
    isSelected: false,
    value: 'your value 2',
 };
}
```

This way you are able to track every options and the current state.

With this change your code has to change a bit here, you need to access the option by the key of the object this way `options[optionKey]`.

I've used `Object.keys`that creates an array of the keys of the object that you pass it, then you iterate through the array and map the key with the options object [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) is the docs that refer to this method in case you've never used it:

```
Object.keys(options).map((optionKey, id) => (
          <Button
            size="lg"
            block
            disabled={ options[optionKey].isSelected } 
            key={optionKey}
            className={`ui floating message options
      ${userAns === options[optionKey] ? "selected" : null}
     `}
            onClick={() => this.checkAns(options[optionKey])}
          >
            {options[optionKey].value}
          </Button>
   ))}
```

Comment: export const Quizdata = [
  {
    id: 0,
    question:
      "If you see this sign on a gate or farm entrance what should you do?",
    options: [
      "You should never enter the area where this sign is displayed",
      "You can enter the area, if you know there is no bull present",
      "Sometimes, these signs are wrong. So it is OK to enter if you take care",
      "Most bulls are tame farm pets. You just have to take care"
    ],
    answer: "You should never enter the area where this sign is displayed",
    picture: ""
  }, this is how my options data is right now

Comment: @dave Could you add it to the main post?  its unreadable here on the comments

Comment: @dave Even better you can create a sandbox and we can see how does it work...

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-shtern-im2rj this is the link can u make the object key running im not able to its saying key not defined

Comment: the disabling doesnt seem to work either could u look at that too

Comment: Im taking a look, and you need to update the `disabled` prop inside the `option` this can be achieved by passing the `id` of the clicked button

Comment: disabled={ options[optionKey].isSelected.id }  like this ? could u copy my codebox and edit it there? or post here

Comment: Check it out i think that is working now it involved more changes but give it a look [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-moon-x0n2s)

Comment: the next button is disabled after the first question that button should be enabled once the user click an option for each question do u know y thats happening

Comment: Youare setting as disabled onthe render method

Comment: Yes @dave this options as an object may be causing alot of errors, you have to adjust it to workwithan object instead of anarray

Comment: @dave have you tried anything on the sandboxes? it could be great to see how is you approaching working, to just check it and find whats wrong, me solving your issue is not the best for you to learn how to handle objects

Comment: @dave You have several problems with your approach, i've made some comments on the same sandbox, check it an try to understand how is the structure working, if you need more help feel free to open other answer specifying whats your issue, and if this question has been solved, just accept the answer or close it

Comment: the issue now is that im not able to pass in the value been clicked by user to check if its correct thats my only issue

Comment: You just have to handle the `checkAnsw` method if it does not contain a parameter `answ`, set the default as `this.state.userAns`, or something similar, other solution could be to write another method that will just check the answer based on the current state.

Comment: did u check my answer below? after introducing objects i cant seem to capture the selected userAns which is causing the problem...what do u mean by the above comment i dont get it

Comment: Check the code its easier to explain there, i just said that you can jut check the current `this.state.userAnswer` if you dont have any `answer` parameter on the `checkAnswer` method

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Quizdata } from "./questions";
//import { FaHorse, FaArrowR } from "react-icons/fa";
import { Button, ProgressBar } from "react-bootstrap";

class Quiz extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isMounted: false,
      disabled: false,
      userAns: null,
      options: {},
      currentQuest: 0,
      scores: 0,
      pictures: "",
      correct: false
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.loadQuiz();
    // console.log("Quiz1 loaded"); //loads quiz 1 data in
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { currentQuest } = this.state;

    if (this.state.currentQuest !== prevState.currentQuest) {
      this.setState({
        disabled: true,
        questions: Quizdata[currentQuest].question,
        options: Quizdata[currentQuest].options,
        answer: Quizdata[currentQuest].answer,
        pictures: Quizdata[currentQuest].picture
      });
    }
  }
  loadQuiz = () => {
    const { currentQuest } = this.state;
    //console.log("QD", Quizdata);
    this.setState(() => {
      return {
        isMounted: true,
        questions: Quizdata[currentQuest].question,
        options: Quizdata[currentQuest].options,
        answer: Quizdata[currentQuest].answer,
        pictures: Quizdata[currentQuest].picture
      };
    });
    //  console.log(this.state.answer);
  };

  nextQuestion = () => {
    const { scores, answer, userAns } = this.state;
    if (userAns === null) {
      return;
    }

    console.log("scores " + this.state.scores);
    this.setState({
      currentQuest: this.state.currentQuest + 1
    });
  };

  checkAns = answer => {
    //userans and answer switched
    let newAnswers = this.state.options;
    // console.log("NewAnsw", newAnswers, answer);
    Object.keys(newAnswers).map(optionKey => {
      newAnswers[optionKey].isSelected = false;

    });
    newAnswers[answer].isSelected = true;

    this.setState({
      userAns: newAnswers.value,
      //  options: newAnswers,
      disabled: false
    });

    console.log("user clicked " + this.state.userAns);
    if (this.state.userAns === answer) {
      console.log("Correct");

      this.setState({
        scores: this.state.scores + 1
        // correct: false
      });
    } else {
      console.log("wrong");
      this.setState({ scores: this.state.scores });
    }
  };
  finishQuiz = () => {
    const { scores, userAns, answer } = this.state;

    if (this.state.currentQuest === Quizdata.length - 1) {
      if (userAns === answer) {
        console.log("Correct");

        this.setState({
          scores: scores + 1
          // correct: false
        });
      } else {
        console.log("wrong");
        this.setState({ scores: scores });
      }
      console.log("scores " + this.state.scores);
    }
  };
  render() {
    const { userAns, options, scores, currentQuest } = this.state;
    // console.log("Opts", options);
    if (!this.state.isMounted) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <ProgressBar animated now={this.state.currentQuest * 10} />
        </div>{" "}
        {this.state.questions}
        <br /> {this.state.scores}
        <br />
        <p style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>Q{this.state.currentQuest}</p>
        {this.state.pictures}
        <br />
        {/*      {options.map((option, id) => (
          <Button
            size="lg"
            block
            key={id}
            className={`ui floating message options
      ${userAns === option ? "selected" : null}
     `}
            onClick={() => this.checkAns(option)}
          >
            {option}
          </Button>
        ))}
  */}
        {Object.keys(options).map((optionKey, id) => (
          <Button
            size="lg"
            block
            disabled={options[optionKey].isSelected}
            key={optionKey}
            className={`ui floating message options
      ${userAns === options[optionKey] ? "selected" : null}
     `}
            onClick={() => this.checkAns(optionKey)}
          >
            {options[optionKey].value}
          </Button>
        ))}
        <div className="hrLine" />
        <br />
        <Button onClick={() => this.checkAns()}>CHECK</Button>
        {currentQuest < Quizdata.length - 1 && (
          <Button
            disabled={this.state.disabled}
            onClick={() => {
              this.nextQuestion();
            }}
          >
            NEXT
          </Button>
        )}
        <br />
        {currentQuest === Quizdata.length - 1 && (
          <Button
            onClick={() => {
              this.finishQuiz();
              // this.nextQuestion();
              //   this.pushtoDB();
              //  this.props.handleDisableValue(scores); // child to parent
            }}
          >
            Finish
          </Button>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Quiz;
```

this is what i worked on i have all working but the user answer cant be used to check if its correct...i saw your updated sandbox i see how u minimized some functions but the score doesnt work either thats the issue im facing now and i want to console the user selected answer when i console i get numbers as its going through the index

Comment: The scores isnt working because you are comparing a `string` (from your correct answer) vs a string that is just a letter that is the value of your `option` , to solve this you can set the correct answer as the key of the option that youve selected

Comment: Its updated check it out, its not optionKey because you are not iterating, it should be `newAnsers[userAnsw].value`somthing like this

Comment: @RicardoGonzalez i want to update the score in the checkAns method rather than in nextQuestion methd but when i moved it it gives me errro saying value not defined

Comment: This change will introduce a lot of issues, is better to check the scores after the user has submited an option, in other case you have to take care of alot of more conditions and updates

Comment: ok seee when u get to the 10th question and u answer it correct  in the console it will only display 1 less than the overall state.scores for some reason last question is not getting updated but the overall score is updated correctly any reason why?@RicardoGonzalez

Comment: Just reviewing quickly i can see that you have another method called `finishQuiz` and there you are handling some logic that may not be updated

Comment: when i put it it goes to the console and prints correct but doest do the score updation tho? https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-vaughan-jgwkm look at the logs when doing qiuz

Comment: this is the main reason in changing the button to be disabled when clicked as i cant update the last question's score @RicardoGonzalez

Comment: @RicardoGonzalez finishQuiz method has same logic as the nextQuestion method and it still doesnt produce the updation that is needed.....if final score is 7 the score in the log is  6 due the last question ansewr not been updated

Comment: @RicardoGonzalez any luck with the above comment

Comment: any luck with above @RicardoGonzalez

Comment: I cant see the changes you made, could you update the sandbox ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-saha-411y3 @RicardoGonzalez here once u get to last question score dosnt update in the console but does in the overall score state any solution to this

Comment: did u see it in the above sandbox @RicardoGonzalez

Comment: I saw your changes and you have several issues, related to **duplicated logic**, try to structure your code and each function should do **only one thing**, This will give you the ability to reuse them. One of the main factors that are complicating your code  is that you are updating the score when the user clicks an answer and not when the user clicks next, this will add a lot of unnecessary logic like calculate the score based on the previous answer and you will have to track it, if you do this on the next function you just need to **evaluate** and **add** or let the score the same way.